# Condition expression on DynamoDB PutItem

Tags: amazon-web-services, go, amazon-dynamodb

I'm trying to use a condition to put a intem on DynamoDB, but doesn't work.

I have a table of users and a attribute id as primary key and attibute name must be unique.

```
conditions := aws.String("NOT contains(email, :e_email)")
attributes := map[string]*dynamodb.AttributeValue{
    ":e_mail": &dynamodb.AttributeValue{
        S: &user.Email,
    },
}
input := &dynamodb.PutItemInput{
    Item:                item,
    TableName:           dynamoTable,
    ConditionExpression: conditions,
    ExpressionAttributeValues: attributes,
}
_, err = dynamo.PutItemWithContext(ctx1, input)
if err != nil {
    if erro, ok := err.(awserr.Error); ok {
        if erro.Code() == dynamodb.ErrCodeConditionalCheckFailedException {
            log.Println("User already exists")
            body, _ := json.Marshal(models.ErrUsuarioJaExiste)
            resp.StatusCode = models.ErrUsuarioJaExiste.CodigoHTTP
            resp.Body = string(body)
            return resp
        }
    }

    log.Println(err)
    resp.StatusCode = models.ErrInterno.CodigoHTTP
    body, _ := json.Marshal(models.ErrInterno)
    resp.Body = string(body)
    return resp
}
```

But I still can add items with the same email

Comment: Note that contains() does a substring match, not an equality match.

Comment: I did test with "NOT email = :e_mail" and "email <> :e_mail" but didn't work too

Comment: I resolved doing a scan befone insert

Comment: That's not ideal for two reasons: a) scan will iterate over the entire table and b) it's possible for some other process to put the same email address between your scan and your put. That said, you can get what you want by making email address a primary key and using a conditional put.

Comment: @Jakson where did you get the syntax of that condition `NOT contains(email, :e_email)` I can't find it in aws' docs

Comment: @jarmod I used this docs, there's no example with NOT contanis()

https://docs.aws.amazon.com/amazondynamodb/latest/developerguide/Expressions.OperatorsAndFunctions.html

Comment: I will try with email as primary key and use attribute_not_exists()
Thank you.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

That's not how conditional expressions work. DynamoDB is not testing *all* items in the table for a matching email. It's testing *this* item for a matching email. Your conditional expression is only being applied to the item whose ID you are actually presenting on the put call, if there is such an item.

Remember that PutItem can be used to insert a new item, but it can also be used to replace existing items. If an item with that ID is absent, which I presume is indeed the case here because you're writing a new ID, then your conditional expression will *never* work.

Make email a primary key then you can use a conditional expression to test for presence and reject duplicate email insertion. Use the attribute_not_exists function with the name of the email attribute.

To read more on this topic, see [Confirming existence or non-existence of an item](https://www.alexdebrie.com/posts/dynamodb-condition-expressions/#1-confirming-existence-or-non-existence-of-an-item).